# Connect via Java client to WCF Service

Tags: c#, java, wcf

I have WCF service which has 2 endpoints: wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding. I can connect to each endpoint  via C# client.

My Wcf Service configuration

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="App.ServiceBehavior"
          name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="/ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBindingForWs"
           contract="Namespace.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="127.0.0.1" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBindingForBasic"
            contract="Namespace.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="127.0.0.1" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:12000/MyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

I can generate wsdl in Java. Can you show me sample code, how can I consume basicHttpBinding in Java?

Answer (score 4):

you can consume the webservice using Java there are different frameworks to make your job easier, like [AXIS](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) and [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

Look at following article for more pointers on same

[Consuming WCF services with Java](http://www.hoonzis.com/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client/)

Comment: I can't use 3rd party libraries in this project.