# How to Call a WCF or Window Service From Java Client?

Tags: java, windows, wcf, service, client

I have a Java app and a button which is used to print documents. While pressing the button, I have to call my WCF Windows service to print that page.

Can your Help me what way it is possible?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656818/consuming-net-wcf-service-from-java  and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559505/connect-via-java-client-to-wcf-service ?

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using to develop your application?
Basically every IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc..) has a tool for Web API / WS integration.

e.g. for Eclipse:

1. select New -> Web Services -> Web Service Client -> Next
2. type in the WSDL path / URL of the WCF Service -> Finish
3. at this point your IDE has generated a WS Proxy / WSDL file, you should be able to view it in Project Explorer
4. no you have write some code for button press action / event

Hope that this helps.

Comment: my wsdl is http://localhost:14560/?wsdl but i cant get all proxy interface and class . i get a class and a interface only in eclipse